# Deployment of Puma with Nginx and Capistrano

Tags: nginx, capistrano, puma

I am running into some issues when I'm trying to deploy my Rails app with Puma and Nginx.
I have a regular Capistrano setup, that has the `puma/capistrano` included.

When running `cap deploy:cold` it works perfectly fine the first time.
After this initial deploy, I'm trying to deploy my changes via `cap deploy`, which results in

```
Bad response from server: 500
```

After I try to use `cap deploy:stop` I'm getting following error:

```
undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass
```

When running `cap deploy:restart` it results in:

```
no such file or directory - "/home/deployer/apps/teachmeo/shared/sockets/pumactl.sock"
```

So, the only way for me after all this to redeploy is cleaning up the `/shared/sockets/` dir and  using `cap deploy:cold` again

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: Puma has amazing support for concurrency in JRuby - That was one of our main decisions to go with puma. puma usually comes with those deploy tasks by default - just somethings seems to be out.

Comment: I think this is an old puma bug that should be fixed the 2.0.0 release https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/192

Comment: Its actually related to this issue https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/246

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/246) which as of today has been patched - although I don't believe a new version of puma containing the patch has been released yet.

If you're using Bundler, you could specifically install the patched version with:

```
gem 'puma', :github => "puma/puma", :ref => "3d1eefbd7e9c72a5173fe017f1b4fe41204beba2"
```

Comment: The latest gem includes this commit, but I'm still getting the same error. I'm using stock standard puma by requiring 'puma/capistrano' in my deploy.rb.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [**Server deployments for Rails + Puma + Nginx + Capistrano 3**](https://coderwall.com/p/ttrhow)

It's a guide that I compiled myself that covers Server Deployments in detail and includes complete `nginx` and `puma` configs, maybe comparing your configuration file with them would help you trace the problem better.